# Locking Fields in Digital Signature 2

Tags: color, forms

I am trying to use eforms to create a pdf where digital signature can be applied. Each document may have more than one digital signature field, i.e so the document can be passed from person to person. I came across a topic on the same manner in [Locking Fields in Digital Signature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88754/locking-fields-in-digital-signature?newreg=29eef48f929e4295b4a324278aefae3d). I have tried to use the code but the package `xcolor` doesn't seem to work properly

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{xifthen}

\def\colFeat{blue!50!black} %Feature Color 1 for Main Color Theme.

\usepackage{eforms}
\makeatletter
    \def\eq@SigField{%
        \centerWidget\eq@rectH%
        \if\autoCenter n\eqcenterWidget=0pt\fi%
        \leavevmode\hbox{\pdfstartlink user{\common@SigFieldCode}%
                \lower\eqcenterWidget\Bbox{\eq@rectW}{\eq@rectH}\pdfendlink%
        }%
        \endgroup%
    }
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mySigField}[5]{
    \begin{varwidth}{#2}
        \textcolor{\colFeat}{
            \fcolorbox{black!5!white}{black!5!white}{
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}%
                    {\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}%
                        {\sigField[\Lock{/Action/Include/Fields [(name#1)(pos#1)]}]{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
                        {\sigField[\Lock{/Action/Include/Fields [(name#1)]}]{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
                    }%  
                    {\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}%
                        {\sigField[\Lock{/Action/Include/Fields [(pos#1)]}]{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
                        {\sigField{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
                    }%
                }\\[1mm]            
            \rule{#2+3mm}{2pt}\\[2mm]
            \begin{tabular}{rl}
                \raggedleft Name: & \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{\TextField[name=name#1,width=6cm]{}}{#4}\\\\[-3mm]
                \raggedleft Position: & \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{\TextField[name=pos#1,width=6cm]{}} {#5}
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{varwidth}
}


\begin{document}

\section{Example of No Related Fields}
\mySigField{}{\WS}{\HS}{John Smith}{Garbo}

\end{document}
```

My goal is to make it work as in the picture below:

[image]

Can someone provide some insight on how can I get to work.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Where can we find the `eforms`package?

Comment: Your code doesn't define \WS and \HS. And what is your problem? What do mean by xcolor not working?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer eforms is part of acrotex. You can find it in miktex or on ctan.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Ah, D.P Story's bundle ...

Comment: Why don't run the code too see what am talking about?

Comment: Ulrike, the above code keeps on complaining I couldn't get to work.

Comment: @user3780018: I don't want to grab CTAN code manually, so give no try

Comment: What exactly doesn't seem to work properly with the `xcolor` package? I can compile your example (if I `\WS` and `\HS`). I'm not really familiar with signing PDFs. I could make a self signed signature and sign the document. It looks more or less like your picture. But the form fields don't seem to be locked after adding the signature. I can still change them. Acrobat does know that they are changed though.

Comment: Oh one other change. If I want the name and position things editable, then they need to be left blank in `\mySigField`.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for your reply and help. Can you post the pdf that you got from the code! mins is still not working!