# How to attach a digital signature to my pdf created by xetex?

Tags: xetex, copyright, security, drm

I want to create a locked document created by `XeLaTeX`, using `\special` command. The instructions are provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24210/is-there-a-package-to-secure-rendered-pdf-with-a-password/237093#237093). By setting `perm` as 0x0904 the document can be signed in Acrobat (If there has been a signature region before).

I have found that [`digsig`](http://home.htp-tel.de/lottermose2/tex/dist/digsig.sty) package and [`eforms`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eforms) package can help me to produce a signature region by loading `pdfLaTeX`. The instructions can be refered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51090/how-do-i-create-a-pdf-file-that-can-be-digitally-signed/52811#52811). However, both of them do not work in `XeLaTeX`, which confuses me a lot (Because I have to create a document by `XeLaTeX`). I wonder if there is a method to make them effective in `XeLaTeX`? If not, is there a better package to support the digital signature?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inserting the following code somewhere would work

```
\special{pdf:ann width 3in height 1in
  <<
    /T (My Signature)
    /Subtype /Widget
    /FT /Sig
    /F 4
    /Q 1
    /MK << /BC [] >>
  >>
}
```

This is XeLaTeX version of what digsig.sty actually does.

Comment: I'm really glad to find that this does work effectively! Thank you a lot for your help.