# Any libraries for encrypting/decrypting latex generated PDF files?

Tags: packages, signatures

There are many commercial systems out there for digitally signing PDF files. Do you know of any latex package that facilitates digital signature?

Comment: Have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51090/220875